# Talking to a Microsoft Geneva server from Java

Tags: java, geneva-framework

Has anyone tried to interact with a Microsoft Geneva Server from Java?

Can it be done easily, using some combination of generally available libraries? If so: What are the important Java libraries/frameworks to look into?

Answer (score -1):

Geneva looks like a Meta-Directory. Normally you don't access a Meta-Directory directly but instead access a directory it manages. You can do this with an LDAP library.